# Using simple_navigation_goals

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am in the process of covering [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) in order to familiarize myself with the packages of `move_base` and `actionlib`. I am aware that the code presented in the tutorial requires move_base server to be run.

My robot platform is a Powerbot (pioneer robot) by ActivMedia Mobilerobots. I am bringing up the following nodes as a standard procedure in order to have my setup up and running:

1. Roscore
2. RosAria package to interface and send commands to the robot's microcontroller
3. Sicktoolbox_wrapper package, to drive the laser range finder
4. TF transformation to get the followin tf tree: odom -> base_link -> laser

I am also using the move_base.launch that is presented in [this repository](https://github.com/husky/husky_navigation/tree/indigo-devel/launch). Since this requires a map to be fired up, I am using the `gmapping` package to create the map.

After I run move_base.launch (from the above repository) and the gmapping.launch file, I followed the rest of the tutorial to be able to run a simple command that moves the robot by 1 metre. When i ran the node `simple_navigation_goals`, I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1425560182.271687421]: Client [/move_base] wants topic /move_base_simple/goal to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped/d3812c3cbc69362b77dc0b19b345f8f5], but our version has [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal/660d6895a1b9a16dce51fbdd9a64a56b]. Dropping connection.
[ INFO] [1425560187.048041843]: Waiting for the move_base action server to come up
[ INFO] [1425560192.048212940]: Waiting for the move_base action server to come up
```

The move_base action server never seemed to "come up" even though I had run the `move_base.launch` file.

Also, in the terminal tab where I ran `move_base.launch`, I had the following, with a warning at the end:

```
[ INFO] [1425560108.210836103]: Using plugin "static"
[ INFO] [1425560108.359553517]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1425560108.700098618]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1425560108.864587000]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1425560108.864730805]: Subscribing to updates
[ INFO] [1425560108.881533417]: Using plugin "inflation"
[ INFO] [1425560109.295686084]: Using plugin "obstacles_laser"
[ INFO] [1425560109.422666966]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser
[ INFO] [1425560109.514106393]: Using plugin "inflation"
[ INFO] [1425560109.778240474]: Created local_planner dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1425560109.795708585]: Sim period is set to 0.20
[ INFO] [1425560110.262923424]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1425560110.412136262]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ WARN] [1425560386.212503542]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 4.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2584 seconds
```

Can someone please explain to me:

1. What kind of move_base launch file do I need to have in order to bring up the move_base action server?
2. Do I need to run other nodes apart from the ones I mentioned previously?
3. How can I use and run this tutorial (simple_navigation_goals) without having to run gmapping?

EDIT: UPDATE:

This is the procedure that I am following to bring up my setup:

1. roscore
2. rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyS0   (runs the rosaria node to drive the robot)
3. rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:=/dev/ttyS1
4. rosrun transform transform (TF code brought from [this tutorial](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/Poineer_mapping)
5. roslaunch gmapping.launch ([gmapping.launch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p04h4ul2zrhnljw/gmapping.launch?dl=0)
6. roslaunch move_base_mapless_demo.launch (obtained from the repository link I posted above)
7. rosrun simple_navigation_goals simple_navigation_goals (I changed the code a bit so that I would know where it is stopping - see code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ep17rcb3couik9y/simple_navigation_goals.cpp?dl=0)

On following this procedure with the files I've posted, the result is this:

**Move_base launch file tab:** The message "Got new plan" was seen

**simple_navigation_goals node tab:** From the ROS_INFO messages I've added to the code I could see that the program halts at `ac.waitForResult()` and in fact, the robot never moves forward and therefore the goal is never reached, i.e. robot is never "done".

Does this have to do with the fact that I am using RosAria to drive the robot? If so, to which frame_id should I publish the goal instruction?

EDIT 2:
I tried to echo /RosAria/cmd_vel in order to see whether the velocity commands were getting through to the driver, but I got nothing. Clearly, the velocity commands and not being published to /RosAria/cmd_vel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204321/using-simple_navigation_goals/) by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you launch the `simple_navigation_goals` node? `move_base` should listen for actions in `move_base/goal` topic and for goal poses in `move_base_simple/goal`. It looks like you have a remap between the two somewhere.

Also, you say you run TF tranformation between map-->odom. Are you publishing this TF by yourself as a static transform? If you are running also `gmapping`, the map-->odom transformation will be also published by this node.

Regarding the other points:

1. The one you are running seems good. The warning you are getting doesn't seem important if you are only getting it once.
2. If you are providing a source of odometry, a map and the map-->odom TF (by `gmapping`) and the lasers, it should be enough.
3. You need to set `move_base` to not use a static map. Try the `move_base_mapless_demo.launch` from the same repository.

**Comments after new edition:**

By default, `move_base` publishes velocities in `cmd_vel` topic. The launchfile you are using actually remaps this default topic to `move_base/cmd_vel`. You need to change in `move_base.launch` (which is called by `move_base_mapless_demo.launch`) the line:

```
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="~cmd_vel" />
```

to

```
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="/RosAria/cmd_vel" />
```

so `move_base` publishes commands in `/RosAria/cmd_vel` topic.

Regarding the other issues, if `move_base` is reporting "Got new plan", it seems that action server is working correctly. Fixing the commands topic will probably the robot to move correctly. The frame_id of the goal should be irrelevant, as long as you have a correct tf tree, but if you want just to move forward, it will be more intuitive if it is in `base_link`.

---

Originally posted by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) with karma: 329 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-05**:
When I ran `rostopic list` I could not see `move_base/goal`, there was only `move_base_simple/goal`. Also, the TF is being published by a separate node (I followed [this tutorial](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/Poineer_mapping)).

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-05**:
Also, what is the reason why when I ran simple_navigation_goals, it kept waiting for move_base action server to come up when I had already ran the move_base node in a separate tab of the terminal?

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2015-03-06**:
The tutorials you are following look good. I would go over all the process step by step and see if I was doing something wrong.
You can also post here all the launch files and rosrun commands you are using in sequence, so we can help you to check if there is something wrong there.

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-06**:
I updated the question to include my most recent developments and where i got stuck now. Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-03-10**:
also alternative is to remap `RosAria/cmd_vel` to whatever move_base publishes to, or remap both to some common name.  Same result, you can remap whichever topic (input or output) you prefer.